# Git submodules and superproject - do we need to do a push on the superproject when pushing to a submodule?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, git-subtree

I am trying to reconfigure a project to use git submodules but not sure whether it is the most appropriate for what I need. For this project, there are 3 components: a bootloader, software for the main board, and software for another board which talks to the main board over I2C. All 3 components are developed independently of each other and do not have anything in common (ie the software from the main board will never need anything from the other software, etc). I thought git submodule would be the most appropriate for this as I have been asked to put all the software related to this project in one place. What we currently have for this is a single git repo where each component is a folder inside the root of the repository.

I have thought of changing this structure as we are trying to use Bitbucket pipelines to build each component, which require a YAML file to be located at the root of the repo. This won't work with how it is currently structured because each component has a different method to be built. So I am looking to put each component to its own git repo so that they can be individually built using Bitbucket pipelines.

Looking at git submodules, my only concern is that when a commit and push is done on a submodule, that a commit to the parent superproject is also required. Is there a way around this? What if the developer checks out the git submodule and just pushes commits only for this submodule, would this reflect on the superproject? I'm not sure if skipping the step of doing a push on the parent superproject would cause something else to break.

I have also looked at git subtrees but it doesn't look to be what I need for the project.

Comment: You need to add and commit in the superproject after making a new submodule commit, so that the (new) superproject commit *refers to* the new submodule commit. You then need to push the new commits from both submodule and superproject if others should have access to them. You can in theory push them in either order, but if you push submodule first, then superproject, that guarantees that there's no race during which someone could grab the new superproject commit before the submodule commit is available.

Comment: (There are ways around it, but they all amount to doing the same thing you'd do by creating a new commit *in* the superproject, so they're not really worth discussing.)

Comment: @torek, if developer1 worked on a submodule by checking out the git repo for this submodule directly instead of the superproject, and did a "git push" for their work, would there be a consequence to this workflow? Say developer2 working on the same project but instead they have the superproject and submodules checked out, can they just do a "git submodule update" with no problems? To update the superproject correctly and get developer1's changes?

Comment: You can make all the new commits you like in the submodule, because the superproject calls for *one specific* commit in the submodule, by its raw hash ID. So whoever has a superproject and doesn't have a clone of the submodule yet runs `git submodule update --init` and gets a clone and checks out the called-for commit by hash ID, and whoever has a superproject and does have a clone runs `git submodule update` and their superproject enters the submodule and checks out the called-for commit by hash ID. Hash IDs and existing commits cannot change.

Comment: This is precisely *why* the superproject calls for commits by hash IDs, and is in turn why you have that inflexible "must make a superproject commit" work-flow for making the superproject refer to a *new* commit *in* the submodule. It's a pain in the butt, but it's manually simulating how Git works internally when *not* using submodules.

Comment: Sorry but it does not describe the case where another developer on the team does not want to work in the superproject, but rather would have indivdually checked out the submodules. As they do not have a copy of the superproject (e.g. they only checked out the repo for the 'bootloader' component as per my example), they have no way of doing the 2nd step where they have to push to the superproject. Would this cause issues within the team if say the other developers in the team actually do the superproject/submodule workflow correctly?

Comment: They can do all the work they like in the submodule. Nobody using the superproject will ever see it! That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks I have tried this myself as well and it is possible. I checked out a copy of the superproject, and one of the submodules separately, did a change in the submodule copy, and pulled in the superproject copy. But I am still unable to grasp the point of doing a push inside the git superproject. If developers can work individually in the submodule, and anyone using the superproject can just do a git submodule update, then why would a push in the superproject still be required? Is it only to keep a history in the superproject? E.g. so that the superproject can be restored to an older point?

Comment: Go back into the superproject and run `git submodule update`. You'll lose the commit you just made in the submodule! The superproject refers to the submodule *by hash ID* and every time you run `git submodule update` the superproject *forces* the submodule to move *to* that hash ID. That's the way it's supposed to work. You make a new commit *in* the superproject to say "use the new hash ID"; if you fail to make such a commit, the superproject still says to use the *old* hash ID.

Comment: Suppose someone changes the bootloader such that it can't load the thing it's supposed to load for the superproject. It works fine for *other* files, but not for the one the superproject needs. Until you test both *together* you don't *want* the superproject to refer to the new submodule commit. The superproject says "this submodule commit WORKS with MY SOFTWARE". You make a new superproject commit to declare that the new submodule commit also works.

Comment: (By the way, when I say "lose the commit in the submodule", I mean the way that people get lost in the woods. They're not gone, they're not dead, they just don't know where they are. Using a GPS they can get found again. The same is true of new submodule commits: something will let you find them. But the superproject refers to an exact coordinate *in* the submodule.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244033/discussion-between-user1397215-and-torek).